# How to find the geometry from the JSON with coordinates?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas

I have multiple JSON and I need to find the geometric type specifically it is Polygon, Point, Multi polygon. Example for the JSON data is given below. Is there any way to find identify the geometry from the coordinates data using python? All I need is to identify if its Polygon, multi polygon or a Point?

```
{
   "geometry":{
      "coordinates":[
         [
            [
               128510.83920000028,
               6632946.9496
            ],
            [
               128500.9031999996,
               6632940.271500001
            ],
            [
               128464.90429999959,
               6632916.0765
            ],
            [
               128433.78110000025,
               6632895.158500001
            ],
            [
               128407.60280000046,
               6632877.7302
            ],
            [
               128399.27969999984,
               6632872.189300001
            ],
            [
               128355.1978000002,
               6632938.6098
            ],
            [
               128333.09640000015,
               6632971.901799999
            ],
            [
               128309.60800000001,
               6633007.1095
            ],
            [
               128293.89910000004,
               6633030.8453
            ],
            [
               128277.66579999961,
               6633055.3730999995
            ],
            [
               128253.11990000028,
               6633101.599300001
            ],
            [
               128262.24289999995,
               6633115.659700001
            ],
            [
               128279.66889999993,
               6633144.6799
            ],
            [
               128276.79650000017,
               6633154.037599999
            ],
            [
               128276.2583999997,
               6633155.413799999
            ],
            [
               128282.10720000044,
               6633158.2322
            ],
            [
               128349.6233000001,
               6633190.7673
            ],
            [
               128359.95590000041,
               6633178.3037
            ],
            [
               128376.82330000028,
               6633157.956900001
            ],
            [
               128378.63430000003,
               6633152.6236000005
            ],
            [
               128383.68369999994,
               6633142.329500001
            ],
            [
               128398.23199999984,
               6633119.9964000005
            ],
            [
               128431.40840000007,
               6633069.0667
            ],
            [
               128443.73680000007,
               6633048.784
            ],
            [
               128498.20990000013,
               6632966.115700001
            ],
            [
               128510.83920000028,
               6632946.9496
            ]
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t there any documentation for the data you have? Theoretically, what you have there *could* be a polygon formed by taking every seventeenth pair of coordinates... it’s impossible to know from just a bunch of numbers!

Having said that...

If it’s GeoJSON data, there should be a `type` entry inside the `geometry` dict.

Failing that, you can always take a guess from the structure of the data — a point should have a single coordinate pair, a polygon should have a list of coordinate pairs for the outer edge, plus possibly more lists for any holes (so it looks like your example is a polygon with no holes), and a multipolygon should have a list of polygons. At least that’s what most geodata would look like.

Comment: Iam trying to create the Geojson by getting the ´type´

Comment: Ture's point is that this is just a list of numbers, so we don't know either! It's not valid geojson, so there's no magic sauce we can apply here - you just need to make assumptions I guess. Since you've only provided a single list of points, we can't really tell how the other geometry types would be formatted either, so we'd just be making things up about your data if we guessed. Can you collect a couple examples of the different types of data you have? Do all the points have one level of nesting, all the polygons two levels, and all the multipolygons three? well then there's your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there are 3 levels of left-brackets before the coordinates (e.g. `[[ [128510.83920000028,6632946.9496]...`) as is in your example then it is most likely a Polygon and in this case it's a Polygon with no inner rings or holes.

Note the posted JSON file is not a valid [GeoJSON](https://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) file since it does not have required "type" property in the geometry object or on the parent Feature object. This would not parse using Shapely or most GeoJSON libraries. Also, it's not WGS-84 with latitude (+/- 90) and longitude (+/- 180) values so without additional info, you need to make some assumptions. It would be helpful to know what coordinate reference system (CRS) it uses.

However, if you have an arbitrary GeoJSON-like JSON data then you can programmatically figure out the type by the content.

Some types will not be easy to distinguish such as LineString from a MultiPoint which are both a collection of points. Also, a Polygon with inner rings and a MultiLineString have the same structure but could check if the first and last points in each segment are the same, which would indicate a Polygon.

Here is some test data.

```python
data = [
   {  # Point example
      "geometry": {
         "coordinates": [30.0, 10.0]
      }
   },
   {  # LineString example
      "geometry": {
         "coordinates": [
              [0, 0], [1, 1], [3, 3]
         ]
      }
   },
   {  # polygon example
      "geometry": {
         "coordinates": [
            [[30.0, 10.0], [40.0, 40.0], [20.0, 40.0], [10.0, 20.0], [30.0, 10.0]]
         ]
      }
   },
   {  # Polygon with inner hole
      "geometry": {
          "coordinates": [
              [[35.0, 10.0], [45.0, 45.0], [15.0, 40.0], [10.0, 20.0], [35.0, 10.0]],
              [[20.0, 30.0], [35.0, 35.0], [30.0, 20.0], [20.0, 30.0]]
          ]
      }
   }
]
```

Here is code to examine the different geometries with above data.

```python
for feature in data:
    feature["type"] = "Feature" # assign Feature type
    geom = feature["geometry"]
    ftype = geom.get("type")
    if ftype:
        # type already defined
        print(ftype)
        continue

    # examine content to determine its type
    geom = feature["geometry"]
    coords = geom.get("coordinates")
    if not coords or len(coords) == 0:
        print("invalid geometry")
        continue
    if isinstance(coords[0], (int, float)):
        if len(coords) >= 2:
            print("Point")
        else:
            print("incomplete/invalid")
    elif isinstance(coords[0], list):
        # line, polygon or other
        if len(coords) >= 2 and isinstance(coords[0][0], (int, float)):
            # LineString or MultiPoint
            print("LineString")
        elif isinstance(coords[0][0], list):
            if isinstance(coords[0][0][0], (int, float)):
                if len(coords) > 1:
                    # Polygon or MultiLineString
                    print("Polygon (with inner rings)")
                else:
                    print("Polygon")
            else:
                # probably MultiPolygon
                print("MultiPolygon")
```

**Output:**

```
Point
LineString 
Polygon
Polygon (with inner rings)
```

In addition to printing the geometry type, you can assign the type to the geometry object; e.g., `geom["type"] = "Polygon"` then export the data to a new GeoJSON file.

```
with open("out.geojson", "w") as fout:
    json.dump({
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": data
    }, fout)
```